Problems dealing with merged cells while extracting a Word table using python-docx
I have this code:
import os
from docx import Document
import pandas as pd

directory = 'the_path_to_the_files'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.docx'):
        docx_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)

        doc = Document(docx_path)
        for i in range(len(doc.tables)):
            table = doc.tables[i]
            data = []
            for row in table.rows:
                row_data = []
                for cell in row.cells:
                    row_data.append(cell.text)
                data.append(row_data)

            if data[0][0] == "search_pattern":
                df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
                df.to_excel(f'Tabel_{filename}.xlsx', index=False)`

I'm trying to import only certain tables, that have a specific search pattern, from multiple word documents, each containing multiple tables, into Excel files.
It works with most tables but when the script encounters a specific table it raises this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "the_path_to_the_python_file.py", line 22, in <module>
    for cell in row.cells:
                ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\docx\table.py", line 368, in cells
    return tuple(self.table.row_cells(self._index))
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\docx\table.py", line 98, in row_cells
    return self._cells[start:end]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\docx\table.py", line 161, in _cells
    cells.append(cells[-col_count])
                 ~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

The specific table has the first cell merged and empty (no data).
I tried to handle empty cells:
for row in table.rows:
    row_data = []
    for cell in row.cells:
        if cell.text.strip():
            row_data.append(cell.text)
        else:
            row_data.append("")
    data.append(row_data)

but it didn't work.
Any ideas what might cause the error and what the solution might be?
